# Using a function call in a case statement label

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Can you have a function call as a case statement label. For instance:

```
char x

switch(x)
{
   case isCapital():
      capitalcount++;
      break;

   case isVowel():
      vowelcount++;
      break;
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .

}
```

Is this permitted within C++?

Comment: What happens when you try it? It *is* possible, you know, to actually experiment to figure out whether something works or not; it's the way programmers have learned things for decades.

Comment: @KenWhite - I thought programming was invented on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Aesthete - no that's in Soviet Russia.

Answer (score 4):

The value in a case label needs to be a constant expression. That is, the answer to your immediate question is: yes, you can call certain functions in a case label. However, not the ones you tried to call. You can have multiple labels refer to one group of statements, though:

```
case 'a':
case 'e':
case 'i':
case 'o':
case 'u':
    do_vowels();
    break;
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this doesn't answer your question per se, but you might try coding it like this....

```
capitalcount += isCapital(x);
vowelcount += isVowel(x);
```

The boolean return type of the isXXX() functions would get promoted to an int and added to the counts as either 0 (false) or 1 (true).

Comment: This works but for sake of readability I'd say to use the result of the function as a boolean data type, so `capitalCount += isCapital(x) ? 1 : 0`

Comment: @Jack - It's one of those "idiom" things.  Code everywhere is full of them.  You can embrace common idioms and write concise code, or you can eschew common idioms, and write what some think is more readable code but others think is cluttered code.  If you become accustomed to the idiom, reading it & understanding it is faster in its idiomatic form.

Comment: I embrace them while I write my own code, I would write it exactly as you but I don't suggest them to users that approach to the language.

Comment: This is technically different from the supposed operation of the original example, because that only counts one or the other whereas this counts both...  assuming that a capital can also be a vowel.  But I suspect the OP meant to have it operate the way you have answered =)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: in your *desired* code `isCapital` and `isVowel` should be not functions (and not a function call, definitely), but **functors** -- because to check a value they have to receive it via parameters...

anyway your code is not possible in C++... but can be simulated with a sequence of pairs of functions: predicate + effect. Predicate have to take some parameter and respond with a boolean. Effect will do smth if predicate is `true`. To simulate break and fallback to next `case` (i.e. when no break in a `case`) *effect* function also have to return a boolean.

Sample code may look like this:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef std::vector<
        std::pair<
            std::function<bool(char)>       // predicate
        , std::function<bool()>             // effect: return true if `break' required
        >
    > case_seq_t;

    unsigned digits = 0;
    unsigned upper = 0;
    unsigned lower = 0;
    unsigned total = 0;
    unsigned other = 0;
    case_seq_t switch_seq = {
        {
            // predicate lambda can be replaced by std::bind
            // in this simple case... but need to change param type.
            // std::bind(&std::isdigit, std::placeholders::_1)
            [](char c) { return std::isdigit(c); }
          , [&]() { digits++; return true; }
        }
      , {
            [](char c) { return std::islower(c); }
          , [&]() { lower++; return true; }
        }
      , {
            [](char c) { return std::isupper(c); }
          , [&]() { upper++; return true; }
        }
        // `default` case
      , {
            [](char c) { return true; }
          , [&]() { other++; return true; }
        }
    };

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        for (int pos = 0; argv[i][pos]; pos++)
            for (const auto& p : switch_seq)
                if (p.first(argv[i][pos]))
                    if (p.second())
                        break;

    std::cout << "digits=" << digits << std::endl;
    std::cout << "upper=" << upper << std::endl;
    std::cout << "lower=" << lower << std::endl;
    std::cout << "other=" << other << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Not so simple as `switch` but (IMHO) obvious enough... and maybe, in some real cases, have better flexibility (and probably maintainability) :)